# TextBox filled with string returned by a method not working C#

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a TextBox1 where one can type a username. And button1 runs this method:

```
public string queryuser(string usrname)
{
    string computername "";
    //some code here what finds out where the user was logged on last time
    return computername;
}
```

I put the result of this method to a TextBox2

```
TextBox2.Text = queryuser(TextBox1.Text);
```

button2 should run the following method and return whatever. Let's say it checks the system type.

```
public string querycomputer(string computername)
{
    string systemtype= "";
    //some code
    return systemtype; //just an example
}
```

Then after clicking the button2 what should run the method like this:

```
querycomputer(TextBox2.Text);
```

I get errors. But if I ctrl+a, ctrl+c, ctrl+v the TextBox2 as it is and push the button2 it works as it should.

I hope I could express myself clean and clear.

Comment: "I get the RPC errors" - what RPC errors? I'm very confused by your question at the moment...

Comment: The point is that it's not working if I simply fill the TextBox2 like that. But if I copypaste it once it does work.

Comment: "it's not working" - what *exactly* do you mean by that? What *exactly* happens, compared with what you expected to happen?

Comment: Well in this case instead of getting if since when is the user logged on on the given PC, the exception message is: The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

Comment: Have you run your code through the debugger and stepped through each method to check that what you think is in each text box is actually in each text box at the time you think it should be?

Comment: So it sounds like some code that is running an RPC is failing. But you didn't mention that code anywhere in your question, which makes it basically impossible to help you.

Comment: It has got not much to do with the RPC because like I said a copy-paste does the trick.
ChrisF: I write the code on my local pc and can only test on the remote server within a domain. So debugging like that is quite hard. But would solve the problem I bet.

Comment: Please google C# The RPC server is unavailable. I get a lot of results for this. Sounds like your connection is not working. Are you running your app as an admin?

Comment: @Nash - if you can't debug then put in some trace statements to write to a log file or even put up a message box so you can see what's going on.

Comment: Is my comment not visible where I say copypasting the TextBox as it is solves the problem? (but I'd like to make it work without copypaste) :)
I know it's very little info and sorry for it the code is 2k lines long.

Comment: @Nash - it's visible, which is why I say debug/put trace statements in. The code is clearly behaving differently in each case so you need to work out why. Following through the execution path in each case will tell you that.

Comment: I'll try ChrisF thanks